# Wildfly: org.jboss.as.controller.registry.FastCopyHashMap

Tags: java, wildfly

While going through the source code of class `org.jboss.as.controller.registry.FastCopyHashMap` in Wildfly 8, I observed that this class is extending `java.util.AbstractMap` and implementing `java.util.Map` at same time.

I understand once we extend `java.util.AbstractMap` we will get all the properties of java.util.Map as well, then why we are implementing `java.util.Map` explicitly.

I would be thankful if someone can explain what I am missing.

PS- I am studying the Wildfly code to learn some best practices, algorithms and to understand how the J2EE specs are being implemented and of course want to contribute to this project in near future.

Comment: Just for a quick reference - 'class FastCopyHashMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>, Cloneable, Serializable'

Comment: Not a single comment yet!!.. Looks like our people are busy taking sunbath on some remote Island during this Holiday season :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to add the `implements Interface` to a super class that implements the interface is to be explicit. It helps when reading the source code, but isn't required.

Comment: Thanks a lot James for taking time to response.